# fetch data from multiple table by sending only one request

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

I am using node.js for server side development and backbone.js for client side development. i want to fetch data from multiple table(more than 3) by sending only one request to node.js. but i cant merge all that result with each other beacuse of asynchronous execution of node.js. i have done this but it sending a lots of get request to node js for getting data from all the tables and because of these performance of my site is become slower. please help me if anyone having any idea.

Comment: I agree. Node.js questions seem to have this problem more than the ASP.NET MVC questions I was answering.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a method which aggregates the results from each of the requests and sends the response back. Basically each of your three async db calls would pass their data to the same method. That method would check to see if it had all of the data it needed to complete the request, and if it did, send the response.

Here is a pseudo code example:

```
function handleRequest(req, res) {
        var results = {};

        db.getUsers(function(data) {
                aggregate('users', data);
        });

        db.getPosts(function(data) {
                aggregate('posts', data);
        });

        db.getComments(function(data) {
                aggregate('comments', data);
        });

        function aggregate(name, data) {
                results[name] = data;
                if(results.users && results.posts && results.comments) {
                        res.send(results);
                }
        }
}
```

This is simplified greatly, you should also of course check for errors and timeouts to the db calls, but this will allow you to wait for all the async commands to complete before sending the data.